# loop for json data extraction

Tags: python, json

this is webhook
. i recive json form api with this . i need extract json tags and send to mysql database . problem is it not sent all json tags . i think it need loop at the step i tag with this step at code . thanks .

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import mysql.connector



urls = ('/.*', 'hooks')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hooks:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        print()
        print('DATA RECEIVED:')
        print(data)
        print()
        cts = data.decode('utf-8') #decode bytes to string
        r1 = cts.replace(cts[:9], '')
        parsed = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(r1)  # ready for post
        print(parsed)
        print(cts)
        print(type(cts))
        myurl = "https://webhook.site/c0e861b0-3cc1-42c2-a0c6-54ad980b01b0"
        req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
        jsondata = parsed
        jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')  # convert to be bytes
        req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
        print(jsondataasbytes)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
        test_dict = json.loads(parsed)[0]
        print(type(test_dict))
        # Extracting specific keys from dictionary <<<<<<THIS STEP>>>>>>>>>
        indic_label = test_dict['indicator_label']
        status = test_dict['status']
        creation_date = test_dict['creation_date']
        laststatus = test_dict['last_status']
        base = test_dict['base_currency']
        quote_currency = test_dict['quote_currency']
        indic = test_dict['indicator']
        prices = test_dict['prices']
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="*",
            user="*",
            password="*",
            database="*"
        )
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO allcoins
            (base,quote_currency  , indic,status,laststatus,creation_date,prices,indic_label)
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                       (base, quote_currency, indic, status, laststatus, creation_date, prices, indic_label))
        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        return 'OK'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

you can post test data to this hook by this curl

```
curl -d "messages=%5B%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22momentum%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22momentum%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+0%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22momentum%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+10%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22leading_span_a%22%3A+%220.00%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22ichimoku%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22leading_span_a%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+true%2C+%22cold%22%3A+true%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Bullish+Alert%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22bbp%22%3A+%220.96%22%2C+%22mfi%22%3A+%2298.05%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22bbp%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+20%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0.09%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0.8%2C+%22std_dev%22%3A+2%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22bbp%22%2C+%22mfi%22%5D%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Lower+Band%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%5D" -X POST http://192.168.30.1
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON you are receiving and which tags are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps define all variables upfront because you still need them to write to the db, then check if they are in the response and update:

```
indic_label = ''
status = ''
creation_date = ''
laststatus = ''
base = ''
quote_currency = ''
indic =''
prices = ''

if test_dict['indicator_label']:
     indic_label = test_dict['indicator_label']
      
if test_dict['status']:
    status = test_dict['status']
...
...
```

If it's an all or none situation, you can check for one variable then exit, otherwise check for each of them.